# SandCastle show different result when generating HTML Help 1(chm) and WebSite(HTML/ASP.NET)

Tags: html, asp.net, namespaces, web, sandcastle

With Sandcastle, when I generate the documentation for 1 project, I want it to show the result for 2 of the 22 namespaces that my solution have.

If I generate it for HMTL Help 1(chm) it works perfectly, as you can see on the attached images. (see first image link)

If I generate it for  WebSite(HTML/ASP.NET) it gives me an index page that all it does is redirecting me for the first namespace documentation file. But I wanted to show the 2, just like the chm. (see second image link)

Images:

Working Perfectly **HTML Help 1 (chm)**

[image: Working perfectly]

Not working as required **Website (HTML/ASP.NET)**

[image: Not working as required]

Comment: Please use the image uploader that's built into the editor.

Comment: I can't use the uploader because of reputation.

Comment: this might be related to another setting, "Enable namespace grouping if supported"

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25022502/generated-index-html-in-sandcastle-only-includes-first-project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are all there, you just have to expand the topmost node. The new VS2013 presentation style website output is modelled after the MSDN content so each page contains a TOC fragment rather than the whole TOC. If you've got conceptual content or have enabled the root namespace container option, it will show them on the default page. It's a side effect of how the TOC fragments are generated. For the next release, I'm going to look into having it expand the root node by default if the specific condition is met that causes it to show as it currently does in the collapsed state.

Comment: Note that the new TOC will always behave best when the first help item is a "Welcome" conceptual topic which does not include any children. An example of this can be seen in the [XML Comments Guide](http://www.ewoodruff.us/xmlcommentsguide/).