# Generated index.html in Sandcastle only includes first project

Tags: html, sandcastle

I'm using Sandcastle Help File Builder to document the projects in a C# solution.  I have it generating HTML Help 1 as well as Website

The HTML Help 1 file generated (.chm) is fine, so I know the basic documentation build process is working, and I can see all my classes.  The website is mostly fine, but it has one serious problem: The index.html only references one project (the first project, alphabetically).   You can access any of the documentation for the other projects in the solution from the index.html file.

Anyone know how to fix the index.html file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved this by checking "Enable namespace grouping if supported" option in the Help File section of Project Properties.

Comment: That should be the default option

Comment: "Enable namespace grouping if supported" - is also works for me
But I've noticed it breaks how namespaces' nodes are expand/collapse

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old. but i bump into this problem too.. I cant use "enable namespace goruping if supported" since its throwing an error..

I also notice that the heirarchy of the html files are

- Help fileName
- namespace 1

namespace is not under the help file name..

so i played with the tool and found out that when enabling on

"Include root namespace container" (dont enable "Enable namespace grouping if supported")

Right now it will give you a heirarchy of

- Help file name
- Title Name
- namespace 1
- namespace 2

namespace 1 and 2 is under tile name its under help file name